# Unusual ray tracing

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

**Background**

Ray tracing is very common in computational geometry and the problem is then to find the point of intersection between the equation of a **line** and the equation of a **plane** in **3D**.

The parametric form of the line is given by

$\mathbf{p}_\mathrm{line}=\mathbf{p}_\mathrm{a} + \xi (\mathbf{p}_\mathrm{b}-\mathbf{p}_\mathrm{a})$

and the plane can be defined by

$\mathbf{p}_\mathrm{plane} \cdot \mathbf{n}+\mathrm{d}=0$,

where $\mathbf{p}_\mathrm{plane}$ is a point on the plane and $\mathbf{n}$ is the normal vector to the plane.

Combining these two equations $(\mathbf{p}_\mathrm{line}=\mathbf{p}_\mathrm{plane})$ gives a convenient expression for the desired point from

$\xi=\frac{-\mathrm{d}-\mathbf{p}_\mathrm{a} \cdot \mathbf{n}}{(\mathbf{p}_\mathrm{b}-\mathbf{p}_\mathrm{a}) \cdot \mathbf{n}}$.

---

**Question**

I now consider the problem of finding the intsersection(s) between an ellipse and a plane in 3D. Is there an effective way to perform this without an iterative scheme?

Comment: Your question is probably a borderline one for this forum.  And it's also unclear.  Do you want light rays to travel on ellipses, is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes. The details depend on how you describe the ellipse, but but most sane choices this reduces to the solution of a quadratic equation. This is mostly not MO-material, really. The faq lists at http://mathoverflow.net/faq#whatnot several other places where you will surely get help.

Comment: I have rewritten the question for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sets you mention (plane, ellipse) can be expressed as the zero sets of certain polynomial functions; you are asking about the set on which both of these polynomials vanish simultaneously -- this is a basic question in algebraic geometry.  One common computational solution is to apply Buchberger's algorithm for computing a Gröbner basis for the corresponding ideal (the basis will give an explicit description of the zero set).  An excellent resource on this subject -- even if you have no background in algebraic geometry -- is the book "[Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387946802)" by David Cox, John Little, and Donal O'Shea.  Additionally, many computer algebra systems (such as [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/products/mathematica/index.html)) provide implementations of these kinds of algorithms.